# Is Windows onresuming and onssuspending equivalent of Android 's on resume and onsuspend

Tags: android, uwp, windows-10-universal, application-lifecycle

Windows app file has `OnResuming` and `Onsuspending` and I'm trying to understand if that is equivalent of android activity's `OnResume` and `OnSuspend`

Basically I have a cross platform project and I'm trying to execute the same code that I execute on Android.

I tried reading this stuff online and it leads to confusion because here in android its activity level event but in Windows its app level event.

Can somebody clarify me please